# Running flask server with gunicorn in Dockerfile

Tags: flask, dockerfile, gunicorn

My dockerfile consists of these lines, in order to start up a flask server:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["/root/server.py"]
```

How would i have to modify these lines, in order to start a Gunicorn server?

Comment: How do you start that server locally? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `boot.sh` Script to your Project with the following content:

```
gunicorn -b :5000 <name_of_your_app_file>:<name_of_your_app>
```

Then change the `ENTRYPOINT` to `['./boot.sh']`

EDIT:

You can run it in the Dockerfile like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT['gunicorn', '-b :5000', 'app:app']
```

Comment: Thank you. But i am sure this can be done from the dockerfile, without requiring an external shell file. I will look it up and update here.

Comment: In the `<name_of_your_app_file>` i place the path+.py file right? So (accodrding to the dockerfile line in my question), it would be `/root/server.py`? But what is the `<name_of_your_app>` entry in your answer?

Comment: The first is just the filename without the .py and the second is the name of you flask app from the call `app = Flask(__name__)`

Comment: This means that if the file is in `/root/server.py` then the first parameter should be `/root/server`? About the second param, my `server.py` file has these lines: `app = Flask(__name__)` and `if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)`. Then the second param should be `__main__`? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No. The first parameter should be `server` the second `app` so: `server:app`